# How can I figure out how to decompile a .rsc file?

Tags: file, extract, decompiler

I've done a bit of research, and it seems that the file type .rsc is used is many different applications. I haven't been able to find any sort of resource extractor or decompiler that can deal with .rsc files.

The objects of my interest: Sounds, images, and other various resources compiled as .rsc files for an old (1999) game made by The Learning Company. Since I have found ways to do this for many other games, I assume that there must be a way to extract and view the resources in their de-obfuscated form.

If nobody has ever figured this out yet, I'm willing to learn about how to write a decompiler and interpret the files. I of course, would need help with that too.

Answer (score 0):

[Ravioli Explorer](http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/other.htm)'s able to extract resources from that since all the other byond extraction tools aren't available. Try using it to open resources.

Comment: Ravioli Explorer (as well as Dragon Unpacker) have been able to extract audio from the files. However, no graphics. Something I noticed when analyzing the files is that they appear to be Pascal DOS executables with MZP signatures. They are matching New Executable (NE) Windows file format, although the file extensions are not .exe. No idea why that's the case, and I have no idea what I can do with that information.